# How to fix missing simulink simulation artificats issue when running test in parallel mode?

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing, azure-devops, simulink, mex

I have 29 Simulink/Matlab Test. It has a lot of different reference models. Before running a 20 second simulation , it has to load all reference models and create a lot of simulation artifacts in a work folder. A lot of reference model are shared in-between test.

When running one test at a time, I have no issue, all simulation artifact are created and used to run the various simulation. Everything Passes.

When running it all via parallel processing. I have a issue.Some simulation artifact are not built or missing, hence my simulation fails even before running.But surprisingly, not all 29 of them fail. It actually random,last time it was 17, another time it was 22. And it even ran once with 0 fail.

Another note, I only have this issue when running it on a self-hosted computer on Azure-Pipelines for CI purposes.

I would like to fix this issue and reproduce stable test pass/fail results of one at a time run, but on parallel process run. How would I do that?

**Error:**

```
2020-11-03T03:16:27.1083996Z Making simulation target "Foo_src_sfun", ...
2020-11-03T03:16:27.1084227Z 
2020-11-03T03:16:27.1084361Z 
2020-11-03T03:16:27.1084502Z 
2020-11-03T03:16:27.1084789Z Microsoft (R) Program Maintenance Utility Version 14.00.24210.0
2020-11-03T03:16:27.1085188Z Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
2020-11-03T03:16:27.1085441Z 
2020-11-03T03:16:27.1085815Z NMAKE : fatal error U1052: file 'Foo_src_sfun.mak' not found
2020-11-03T03:16:27.1086175Z Stop.
```

```
2020-11-03T03:16:27.1089399Z ================================================================================
2020-11-03T03:16:27.1089936Z Error occurred in TestSim/testSim(File=test_FooTest1_slx) and it did not run to completion.
2020-11-03T03:16:27.1090308Z 
2020-11-03T03:16:27.1090497Z     ---------
2020-11-03T03:16:27.1090720Z     Error ID:
2020-11-03T03:16:27.1090946Z     ---------
2020-11-03T03:16:27.1091254Z     'Slvnv:simcoverage:SimulationFailed'
2020-11-03T03:16:27.1091481Z 
2020-11-03T03:16:27.1091669Z     --------------
2020-11-03T03:16:27.1091919Z     Error Details:
2020-11-03T03:16:27.1092186Z     --------------
2020-11-03T03:16:27.1092419Z     Error using cvsim
2020-11-03T03:16:27.1092659Z     Simulation failed
2020-11-03T03:16:27.1092864Z     
2020-11-03T03:16:27.1093112Z     Error in testRunner (line 145)
2020-11-03T03:16:27.1093477Z             [cvdo, simOutRes] = cvsim(testObj,paramStruct) ;
2020-11-03T03:16:27.1093765Z     
2020-11-03T03:16:27.1094034Z     Error in TestSim/testSim (line 30)
2020-11-03T03:16:27.1094373Z                 [cvdo, simOutRes, ErrLog] = testRunner(File,20);
2020-11-03T03:16:27.1094638Z     
2020-11-03T03:16:27.1094830Z     Caused by:
2020-11-03T03:16:27.1095168Z         Error using autobuild_kernel>autobuild_local (line 219)
2020-11-03T03:16:27.1095612Z         Unable to create mex function 'Foo_src_sfun.mexw64'
2020-11-03T03:16:27.1096006Z         required for simulation.
2020-11-03T03:16:27.1096427Z ================================================================================
```

**Update:**

I found that I have also another kind of error, leads pretty much to same result.

```
2020-11-03T03:18:36.1668328Z Making simulation target "Foo2_src_sfun", ...
2020-11-03T03:18:36.1668601Z 
2020-11-03T03:18:36.1668735Z 
2020-11-03T03:18:36.1669087Z 'Foo2_src_sfun.bat' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
2020-11-03T03:18:36.1669483Z operable program or batch file.
2020-11-03T03:18:36.1669685Z 
2020-11-03T03:18:36.1669892Z >>Removing MiL paths...
2020-11-03T03:18:36.1670104Z >>Done
```

Comment: According to your description, it's all fine when you run a single job. But error generated when you run the tests in parallel. How did you set the parallel in  Azure pipeline side? Better share a related screenshot. Do you have multiple self-agents  in your  agent pool?

Comment: @PatrickLu-MSFT, I didn't set up parallel processing using Azure Pipelines. Instead I used Matlab spmd & runInParallel functions to do just that. Note, i added a fix below. If you have a more elegant solution or can explain why the one below works, it would be great.

Comment: I have one self-hosted agent in my pool, it's my computer. When using matlab parallel toolbox it divided my task in 17 groups on 6 matlab worker pools.Note, any good reference or example on azure pipeline parallel processing would be nice too, for my personal reading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a runSingleTest() that I run before my parallel run. Before running it creates all required model reference mexw64 files in the **/work/sim_artifact folder.

Hence when the parallel run they don't need to create any new files, they either use whats already there or update the files.

I have been having no issue since that change. Just a longer run time because of that repetitive test.

Comment: If their is a more elegant way apply same fix, i'm all hears?